# UWP Tile with blue background and white image in the midle

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my `UWP` app, I created a tile using this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#generating-all-assets-at-once). In the tutorial, I added the source as a `pdf` file (that has a white background), and kept the tile background as default (transparent). But when I generate the tiles and run the app, the tile on the start menu looks as the third picture shown below. I want it to look something like the first or second picture shown below (the picture does not have to be the same but the look and feel should be similar). How can we achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your foreground image has full opacity set? It doesn’t seem so...

Comment: @LucaLindholm I just changed two words in my post. The source is a pdf file, and the  tile background is the default `transparent`. But I have also tried using an image of the same pdf file, but I still get the same result. What I need is something similar to the first two images. Any suggestions?

Comment: I still don’t get what is your goal...

Comment: @LucaLindholm Instead of the symbol `e`  (shown in the second image above) I need to display a Greek letter, say, `pi` or `summation` with the same size, look and feel as in the image two above.

Comment: Well, I assume that it is an image format problem, probably.